# Session object destruction failed error with CakePHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp

I'm following this tutorial http://www.queness.com/post/1450/jquery-photo-slide-show-with-slick-caption-tutorial-revisited

And everything seems to be going fine, but I just checked in IE6 and IE7 and I'm getting the following error message

```
Warning (2): session_destroy() [function.session-destroy]: Session object destruction failed [CORE\cake\libs\cake_session.php, line 458]
```

I'm using cakephp and obviously the error message says it's something to do with that. Unfortunately noone else on the tut's comments has had the same issue.

Anyone got any ideas :)

Comment: Ah, ok, feel wick. It seems to miraculously work now. Although for some reason the png images I'm using aren't appearing in Opera. Fine in safari chrome FF & IE. Weird. Does Opera not like png or something?

Answer (score 1):

Well, being a PHP programmer, you could look at the source code for the version of CakePHP that you are running (it gives you the file and line number) and then look at any PHP functions it might be calling.

I'm willing to bet on that line (or somewhere near to it) having a call to PHP's [`session_destroy`](http://php.net/session_destroy) or [`session_regenerate_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) functions, and that other people have had this error and you'll be able to find information about it in the PHP docs (hint: there's info in the second link - search the page for 'destruct').

Answer (score 0):

We will need more of you code, that error is in your cake php code. The tutorial as it stands doesn't use CakePHP.