# Warning (2): session_regenerate_id(): Session object destruction failed

Tags: php, cakephp

I have setup user login in cakephp with Auth. In core.php I have set sessions to be handled like below so that on every page load the session is renewed

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'cake',
    'timeout' => 180,
    'cookieTimeout' => 1440,
    'checkAgent' => false,
    'autoRegenerate' => true,
    'requestCountdown' => 1
));
```

Still sometimes I get this warning:

```
Warning (2): session_regenerate_id(): Session object destruction failed
```

And after the next click the user is logged out. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573104/session-object-destruction-failed-error-with-cakephp And this https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/5126

Comment: You need to dig into cakephp code.

Comment: I read that article, but there was no solution to the question. Also it was in combination with login from linked in and with me that is not the case. Login works fine, only randomly I get kicked out with this warning before. So on page load I get this warning and any other click will lead me to the logout

Comment: Check line number where do you get error and then backtrace into core code.

Comment: It's very random in any controller/action

Comment: dont you get Line number in error message really ?

Comment: Try using another session handler AFAIR `cake` is using the file system and writes into the tmp folder or something like that. Try `php` - which is doing basically the same - or try Redis. But I guess this is related to file system locks and the `cake` session adapter. Also name your *specific* CakePHP version.

Comment: Really... no line number :(